# How do I evaluate JavaScript expressions server-side using .NET Core?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, scripting, jscript

I'm building an expression engine that I want to script using JavaScript.  In .NET Framework it was possible to use the JScript library to evaluate JavaScript expressions.  However in .NET Core JScript isn't currently supported.  Also the existing libraries(NodeServices/SpaServices) have been deprecated.  **What is the best solution for achieving something like:**

```
    var result = SomeJavaScriptEvaluator.Eval("1 + 1"); //2
    var isConditionTrue = SomeJavaScriptEvaluator.Eval("someValue !== null"); //true or false
```

Comment: If you want a library, you can probably ask this on **https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com** after reading their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336).

Comment: Yep. Sailing close to the wind on a product recommendation here. https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

So [ClearScript](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript) provides the answer to this.  It is an implementation of the V8 JavaScript engine and provides methods to invoke JavaScript expressions.